# Flink: handle skew by partitioning by a field of the key

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have skew when I keyBy on my data. Let's say the key is:

```
case class MyKey(x: X, y:Y)
```

To solve this I am thinking of adding an extra field that would make distribution even among the workers by using this field only for partitioning:

```
case class MyKey(z: evenlyDistributedField, x: X, y:Y) extends MyKey(x, y) {
    override def hashCode(): Int = z.hashCode
}
```

due to [this](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/e85cf8c4cdf417b47f8d53bf3bb202f79e92b205/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/KeyGroupRangeAssignment.java#L65) line my records will use the overridden hashCode and be distributed evenly to each worker and use the original equals method (that takes into consideration only the X and Y fields) to find the proper keyed state in later stateful operators.

I know that same (X, Y) pairs will end in different workers, but I can handle that later. (after making the necessary processing with my new key to avoid skew).

My question is where else is the hashCode method of the Key is used?

I suspect for sure [when getting keyed state](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/e85cf8c4cdf417b47f8d53bf3bb202f79e92b205/flink-runtime/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/runtime/state/heap/StateMap.java#L66) (what is namespace btw?) as I saw extending classes use the key in a hashMap to get the state for this key. I know that retrieving the KeyedState from the map will be slower as as the hashCode will not consider the X, Y fields. But is there any other place in the flink code that uses the hashcode method of the key?

Is there any other way to solve this? I thought of physical partitioning but I cannot use keyBy as well afaik.

**SUMMING UP I WANT TO**:

- partition my data in each worker randomly to produce an even distribution
- **[EDITED]** do a .window().aggregate() in each partition independently from one another (as if the others dont exists). The data in each window aggregate should be keyed on (X,Y)s of **this partition** ignoring same (X,Y) keys in other partitions.
- merge the conflicts due to same (X,Y) pairs appearing in different partition later (This i need not guidance. I just do a new key by on (X, Y))

Answer (score 1):

In this situation I usually create a transient `Tuple2<MyKey, Integer>`, where I fill in the `Tuple.f1` field with whatever I want to use to partition by. The `map` or `flatMap` operation following the `.keyBy()` can emit `MyKey`. That avoids mucking with `MyKey.hashCode()`.

And note that having a different set of fields for the `hashCode()` vs. `equals()` methods leads to pain and suffering. Java has a contract that says "equals consistency: objects that are equal to each other must return the same hashCode".

[updated]

If you can't offload a significant amount of unkeyed work, then what I would do is...

1. Set the `Integer` in the `Tuple2<MyKey, Integer>` to be `hashCode(MyKey) % <operator parallelism * factor>`. Assuming your `parallelism * factor` is high enough, you'll only get a few cases of 2 (or more) of the groups going to the same sub-task.
2. In the operator, use `MapState<MyKey, value>` to store state. You'll need this since you'll get multiple unique `MyKey` values going to the same keyed group.
3. Do your processing and emit a `MyKey` from this operator.

By using `hashCode(MyKey) % some value`, you should get a pretty good mix of unique `MyKey` values going to each sub-task, which should mitigate skew. Of course if one value dominates, then you'll need another approach, but since you haven't mentioned this I'm assuming it's not the case.

Comment: Tuple.f1 you mean Tuple._1 right? Which in our case is MyKey in Tuple2<MyKey, Integer>. What is the purpose of Integer? Also when you say 'can emit Mykey' you mean drop it and replace it with a new one so the KeyedState can use the new key without redestributing the data across the cluster with this new key?

Comment: What happens to the messages that end up in the same worker node after KeyBy? Will they be serialized or not? If not the transient keyword will not work

Comment: 1. No, in Java `Tuple.f0` is the first entry (`MyKey`), and `Tuple.f1` is the second field (`Integer`). So the integer is used in the `keyBy()` to do the partitioning.
2. By "can emit `MyKey`", I'm saying that's the output type of the operator that follows the `keyBy()`.
3. By "transient" I mean a record that is short-lived (not persisted) in the workflow, not a Java/Scala "transient".

Comment: the problem is that after `.keyBy()` I want to do `.window().aggregate()` and each window will not be for MyKey but for Integer because that is what we keyed by

Comment: You'll need to do another `.keyBy()` on `MyKey`, following the initial processing. If you can't offload some significant amount of the work to a non-keyed operator, then see my (edited) answer above for an alternative approach.